# easy tool to filtering columns with specific conditions using pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm wondering if exist a tool in python to filter data between columns that follow an specific condition. I need to generate a clean dataframe where all the data in column 'A' must have the same consecutive number in column 'E'(and this number is repeated at least twice). Here an example:

```
df
Out[30]: 
         A         B           C          D           E
6        1       2.366       8.621      10.835        1
7        1       2.489       8.586      10.890        2
8        1       2.279       8.460      10.945        2
9        1       2.296       8.559      11.000        2
10       2       2.275       8.620      11.055        2
11       2       2.539       8.528      11.110        2
50       2      3.346       5.979      10.175         5
51       3       3.359       5.910      10.230        1
52       3       3.416       5.936      10.285        1
```

The output will be:

```
df
Out[31]: 
         A         B           C          D           E
7        1       2.489       8.586      10.890        2
8        1       2.279       8.460      10.945        2
9        1       2.296       8.559      11.000        2
10       2       2.275       8.620      11.055        2
11       2       2.539       8.528      11.110        2
51       3       3.359       5.910      10.230        1
52       3       3.416       5.936      10.285        1
```

Comment: Your requirement and output dataframe are contradicting?

Comment: 3 is not present in E

Comment: The idea is to remove that rows that not present consecutive numbers in E in reference with the column A

Comment: In all due respect, that makes no sense.  Please spend more time than just one sentence to explain the logic.

Comment: Oh I get it... Give me a second

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are looking for is:

```
import numpy as np

df.groupby((df.E != df.E.shift(1)).cumsum()).filter(lambda x: np.size(x.E) >= 2)
# or
df[df.groupby((df.E != df.E.shift(1)).cumsum()).E.transform('size') >= 2]
```

Output:

```
    A      B      C       D  E
7   1  2.489  8.586  10.890  2
8   1  2.279  8.460  10.945  2
9   1  2.296  8.559  11.000  2
10  2  2.275  8.620  11.055  2
11  2  2.539  8.528  11.110  2
51  3  3.359  5.910  10.230  1
52  3  3.416  5.936  10.285  1
```

Explanation:

You want to keep all records where there is a consecutive group in `E` which has a size of more than 2.

The first part `(df.E != df.E.shift(1)).cumsum()` allows you to label consecutive groups in column `E`, and then you group by that label and filter the `DataFrame`, keeping only groups where the size is 2 or more.

Comment: That's what I want, appreciated! and sorry for my bad english

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to do something like the following:

```
mask = (df['E'] == df['E'].shift(1)) | (df['E'] == df['E'].shift(-1))
filtered_df = df[mask]
```

Comment: This is a very efficient solution for finding consecutive groups of 2+.